# What was the Boy's dog?

Tags: plot-explanation, bird-box

At the beginning of *Bird Box*, Malorie tells the children

> Boy, you have your dog. Girl, you have your kitty.

We later find that the Girl's cat is her mother's *Hello Kitty* plushie. **What was the Boy's dog?**

Did I miss something in the movie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the scenes where she's putting the kids into the boat, right in the beginning, there is a shot from behind the kids. You can see a small dog toy on the bag of the boy. While it wasn't a baby shower gift, we can assume that they picked that up on one of their regular supply runs.

[image]

The novel has a real dog that they adopt, they find by the side of a dead family. But in the movie, it's just a toy.

Comment: So Netflix stops you from taking screen grabs. :(
It's like this small blue clip on toy. Also the movie makers just used it as a dialogue for sake of completion. While they later stress on the kitty, they ignore the dog toy altogether. Even in the boat, the girl holds on to her toy, the boy's like "yeah, whatever"

Comment: 03:15 - 03:20 (mm:ss) you can glimpse the toy hanging from the boy's bag